# Position a btn to absolute top right of a dialog with vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Using Vuetify, I want to have a  that has a  that overflow on the top right of the dialog.

```
<v-dialog>
  <div style="width: 400px; heigth=400px;">
    <v-btn
      fab
      absolute
      top
      right
    >
      <v-icon>
        mdi-plus
      </v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</v-dialog>
```

Using the code above, the button gets position on the top right of the entire page after sticking to the top right of the dialog itself for a very brief moment. I don't know why I have this behaviour. Anyone could tell me how I get it to stay in top right of the dialog?

Comment: I tried adding absolute with the top and right attribute with the parent set via style attribute.
These attributes (fab right top absolute) don't do anything.
How do they work exactly?

Comment: It's been a while but back then fab was for 'floating action button' it cane with many css attrijutes to make the button look round and floating. Absolute was basically "position: absolute" styling. It most likely changed in the newest versions if vuetify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. Turns out all that was missing is a 'position: relative' in the style of the div :

```
<v-dialog>
  <div style="position: relative; width: 400px; height: 400px;">
    <v-btn
      fab
      absolute
      top
      right
    >
      <v-icon>
        mdi-plus
      </v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</v-dialog>
```